# How to exec into a **node** (not container) via kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How to exec into a K8s **node**?

Up to now I only found ways to exec into containers running on a node.

I would like to avoid `ssh`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The layer above a pod (and their containers) is the operating system (excluding logical layers of k8s).

There isn't any tools (that im aware of) specifically part of kubernetes management tooling that do this - that's what SSH is for.

Comment: The `kubectl node-shell` solution from another answer works just fine. Put aside that it can be ideologically imperfect.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [kubectl-node-shell](https://github.com/kvaps/kubectl-node-shell)

> kubectl-node-shell: Start a root shell in the node's host OS running.

Usage:

```
# Get standard bash shell
kubectl node-shell <node>
```

*You need to be able to start privileged containers for that.*

Comment: perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can start a pod with more privileges.
You could e.g. do a hostpath mount on /. With some linux knowledge this should be enough.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: evil-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: evil
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: "-c" ,"sleep infinity"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /host
      name: host-root
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /
      type: ""
    name: host-root
```

Be aware, that this is of course a security issue and in a secure cluster should not be possible.
If you have to maintain the node, use ssh as suggested by samson

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to the underlying Nodes for your Kubernetes cluster (and you don't have direct access - usually if you are hosting Kubernetes elsewhere), you can use the following deployment to create Pods where you can login with `kubectl exec`, and you have access to the Node's IPC and complete filesystem under `/node-fs`. To get a node console that is just like you have SSHd in, after logging in, perform `chroot /node-fs`. It is inadvisable to keep this running, but if you need access to the node, this will help. Because it is a DaemonSet, it starts one of these Pods on each Node.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: privpod
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      mydaemon: privpod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        mydaemon: privpod
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      hostPID: true
      hostIPC: true
      containers:
        - name: privcontainer
          image: johnnyb61820/network-toolkit
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          command:
            - tail
            - "-f"
            - /dev/null
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nodefs
              mountPath: /node-fs
            - name: devfs
              mountPath: /dev
      volumes:
        - name: nodefs
          hostPath:
            path: / 
        - name: devfs
          hostPath:
            path: /dev
```

This is from Appendix C.13 of [Cloud Native Applications with Docker and Kubernetes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484288750).  I've found this useful especially if I need to deal with physical drives or something similar.  It's not something you should leave running, but helps when you are in a pinch.